# the "this" keyword is disallowed outside of a class body

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, codacy

I have function, here is code

```
function remove_multi_leg(): void  {
  if (Number($("#search_no_legs").val()) < 2) {
    return;
  }

  const removeId: number = Number($(this).attr("data-number"));
  const highestId: number = Number($("#search_no_legs").val());

  if (removeId === highestId) {
    $(`#multi_leg_${removeId}`).hide();
    $("#search_no_legs").val(highestId);
    return;
  }

  let i: number;
  let end: number;
  let asc : boolean;
  for (i = removeId, end = highestId, asc = removeId <= end; asc ? i <= end : i >= end; asc ? i += 1 : i -= 1) {
    $(`#search_legs_${i}_origin_text`).val($(`#search_legs_${i + 1}_origin_text`).val());
    $(`#search_legs_${i}_origin_id`).val($(`#search_legs_${i + 1}_origin_id`).val());
    $(`#search_legs_${i}_destination_text`).val($(`#search_legs_${i + 1}_destination_text`).val());
    $(`#search_legs_${i}_destination_id`).val($(`#search_legs_${i + 1}_destination_id`).val());
  }
  $(`#multi_leg_${highestId - 1}`).hide();
  $("#search_no_legs").val(highestId - 1);
  return;
}
```

But I have strange error when codacy analyse code

Here is it

> `the "this" keyword is disallowed outside of a class body`

In this row

> `const removeId: number = Number($(this).attr("data-number"));`

How I can fix it?

Comment: Is `remove_multi_leg` supposed to be called as some element event callback or as some object method?

Comment: It's called like this `$(".remove_multi_leg").parent().off("click").on("click", remove_multi_leg);` @PatrickEvans

Comment: I not understood how to solve it @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor that function not to use `this` by accepting the argument and using the argument's `currentTarget` property instead:

```
function remove_multi_leg(e: Event): void  {
   const target = $(e.currentTarget);
   // ...
   const removeId: number = Number(target.attr("data-number"));
   // ...
}
```

(The type of `e` could be `MouseEvent` specifically for `click`, which adds `x` and `y`.)

[`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) and `this` refer to the same thing in a DOM event handler (in the normal course of things), it's the element you hooked the event on (as opposed to [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), which may be a descendant of the element you hooked the event on).

Comment: But which type will be `const target`?

Comment: @Balance - TypeScript will infer it for you as `EventTarget`, which may or may not be what you want. :-) You could cast it to `HTMLBaseElement`, so `const target = (HTMLBaseElement)e.currentTarget;`.